# Opening SHP file in RStudio

Tags: r, shapefile, r-maptools

I've a package of five files with all French administrative limits (available [here](https://wxs-telechargement.ign.fr/o3oy9vz86yrzwkybf39odpfd/telechargement/inspire/GEOFLA_THEME-DEPARTEMENTS_2012_GEOFLA_1-1_SHP_LAMB93_000_2013-01-14/file/GEOFLA_1-1_SHP_LAMB93_000_2013-01-14.7z)).
All these five files LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT.SHP/DBF/AVL/PRJ/SHX are in a the folder /home/jonathan/R.

I use this code :

```
library(maptools)
setwd('/home/jonathan/R')
france<-readShapeSpatial("LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
```

which gets me:

```
Error in read.dbf(filen1) : unable to open DBF file
```

I've tried in R (3.0.1) and in Rstudio (0.97.551).
I've also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607532/error-opening-shp-file-in-r-using-maptools-readshapepoly) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607532/error-opening-shp-file-in-r-using-maptools-readshapepoly). But, now I've no idea about what I can do...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is related to the fact that the extension of the dbf file is `.DBF` and not `.dbf`, so one workaround is just to rename it.

And it's better to use the `rgdal::readOGR` function  to read shapefile in R.

I have the shape file on my `/tmp` folder so change it to your actual path make it work

```
require(rgdal)
file.copy(from = "/tmp/LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT.DBF", 
          to = "/tmp/LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT.dbf")
file.remove("/tmp/LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT.DBF")
depart <- readOGR(dsn = "/tmp", layer = "LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT")
str(depart, max.level = 2)
## Formal class 'SpatialLinesDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 4 slots
##   ..@ data       :'data.frame':  330 obs. of  2 variables:
##   ..@ lines      :List of 330
##   .. .. [list output truncated]
##   ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 99226 6049647 1242375 7110524
##   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
```

Comment: Bingo ! It was so simple... (and tricky) Thanks, thanks, thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

I also begin with R (in french…), and I had a similar problem, with the same message you get. And I've discover a solution : I've just insert the precisely way to the .shp file. For example, with my Mac : /Applications/R/DEPARTEMENT/DEPARTEMENT.SHP.
The repertory GEOFLAT 2014 (containing the file 'DEPARTEMENT.SHP') had been download from the IGN website (Institut géographique national). In first time, I had changed 'SHP' for 'shp' (and writed like that in R consol : 'DEPARTEMENT.shp') : no result. In a second time, I've thinked to mean the completed path to the file : and success.

I used 'maps' and 'maptools' extensions (with 'sp' and so one).

Try it, please, and answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `readOGR(dsn = "/path/to/data", layer = "LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT", ...)` that comes along with `rgdal`. It usually has no problems with .dbf files.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to turn on the foreign package to read the .dbf files.

Comment: Foreign package is now turned... and nothing change. I've also tried « france<-read.dbf("LIMITE_DEPARTEMENT", package="foreign") »

Comment: I tried with shape<-readShapeSpatial("path_to_shape/shape.shp") and it worked.

Comment: grrr ... so what's happenning here ? If I rename files in "shape.shp" and "shape.dbf", the error became "error opening SHP file". // Do you use any other package ? sp/gripd/lattice/gpclib ?

Comment: actually no.. I have installed sp and maptools.