# error using readShapeSpatial()

Tags: r, shapefile

I am trying to use the below code using maptool:

```
stateShape <- readShapeSpatial("tl_2013_us_state")
```

but i get an error:

```
Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file
```

my directory is correct

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607532/error-opening-shp-file-in-r-using-maptools-readshapepoly)?

Answer (score 3):

To read in spatial data you need the `.shp`, `.shx`, and `.dbf` files. You get the following behaviour if bits are missing:

NO error if all there:

```
> m=readShapeSpatial("metro")
```

Let's remove the `.dbf`

```
> file.remove("metro.dbf")
[1] TRUE
> m=readShapeSpatial("metro")
Error in read.dbf(filen1) : unable to open DBF file
```

Now without the `.shx`:

```
> file.remove("metro.shx")
[1] TRUE
> m=readShapeSpatial("metro")
Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file
```

which looks like your error. Do you also have the corresponding `.shx` file?

Shapefiles may also have a `.prj` file, but `readShapeSpatial` ignores this, which is why you shouldn't use it. ALWAYS use the `rgdal` package:

```
> m = readOGR(".","metro")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "metro"
with 5 features and 12 fields
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
> summary(m)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min       max
x -96.90567 -95.84013
y  40.99636  41.74546
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
```

Note the correctly-set `proj4string` value. You don't get that with `readShapeSpatial`.